# How do you do math operations from a file in java?

Tags: java, math, java.util.scanner, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I recently started going to programming competitions for high school students in java. Last competition, I was able to solve a few problems. One of the problems I couldn't solve was one where I had to take input from a file and do math operations. This is the actual problem:

> **Input:**
>   The first line contains integer *n* that represents the number of data sets to follow. Each data set contains a prefix, infix or postfix expression, with thw operators and operands separated by spaces. Note: Integer division applies.
>
> **Output:**
>   For each data set, print the value of the evaluated expression.

Here is the sample input and the sample output.

> **Sample Input:**
>   5
>   1 + 1
>   7 9 3 4 6 7 - + * / + 8 6 - +
>   + - + 2 * 4 8 + 2 8 8
>   (50 + 12) ^ 2 - 90
>   + / * 2 3 4 / - 1 3 / - ^ 6 2 4 6
>
> **Sample Output:**
>   2
>   10
>   32
>   3754
>   1

If someone could help me with this I would be really grateful. This is going to help me prepare for my next competition.

Can someone at least guide me through what I should be looking at to find the answer to this.

Comment: You need to understand how to express these math expressions as parse trees and walk them using prefix, infix, or postfix iteration.  It's rather broad.  I'd advise using this comment as a spur to your research efforts.  Come back with specific questions about your implementations.

Comment: One suggestion: Find out how to handle postfix expressions first.  Basically it involves a stack, and when you see `+` or another operator, there need to be two numbers on the stack and you add them.  If there's only one number on the stack, then assume you have an infix expression, and start over treating the expression as infix.  If there are zero numbers on the stack, then assume you have a prefix expression.  You'll still need to learn to handle all three kinds, but that's one way you can choose with kind you're dealing with.

Comment: A simpler version of my comment would be to count the number of number tokens before you see the first operator token, and use that to determine whether it's a prefix, postfix, or infix expression.  If you see `(`, then it's an infix expression since parentheses aren't used in the other kinds of expressions.

Comment: Are you having trouble with the concepts of infix, prefix and postfix? Or the programming of math operations based on text input?

Comment: I figured out how to solve prefix and postfix, but I still haven't figured out how to do infix operations from a string

Comment: Agreed, infix is unusual. I suggest you search for "infix to prefix conversion" or perhaps see http://scanftree.com/Data_Structure/infix-to-prefix.